# Change typeform iframe height

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a typeform iframe and I want to change it is height 
I have used this code but it doesn't work 
The typeform iframe doesn't show by default; it is shown after you click on a id element

This is my code
Don't hesitate if you need any clarification

```
$('iframe[src*="typeform"]').attr("min-height","90%");
```

Other method

```
$('iframe[src*="typeform"]').attr("style","border: 0px; height: 1px; min-height: 90%; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; width: 0px;");
```

None of them is working;Is there any alternative in Javascript
,
Thanks in advance

Comment: May be `$('iframe[src*="typeform"]').css("min-height","90%");`

Comment: Thanks but this one causes this error

Comment: VM1861:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:29

Answer (score 2):

You can give `id` to `iframe` tag and try below code:

```
$("#iframe_id").attr({'width':'1000px','min-height','90%});
```

Likewise, you may use css as many you want.

Comment: I have no access to modify the id of the iframe, I just can handle it as it is

Comment: Than you can use $('iframe[src*="typeform"]').attr({'width':'1000px','min-height','90%});

Answer (score 1):

try this code, with css function:

```
$('iframe[src*="typeform"]').css({"border":"0px","height":"1px",...})
```